# Why do the turtles total number vary from the ones defined in the UI vs agent setup?

Tags: user-interface, rounding, netlogo, agent

I'm asking Netlogo to create turtles that represent old, middle-aged and new cars as agents, each with a certain fixed percentage (65%, 30% and 5%, respectively). I have a slider in the UI that sets up the total amount of cars and the code calculates these proportions. What's happening is that not every time I get that exact amount of agents in set-up. E.g., for 10 agents set in the UI, I get a total of 9 vehicles being set-up, where 6 are old, 3 are middle-aged and 0 are new. I guess I expected the code to round these numbers in a way to make the total agents that are setup match the ones that are displayed in the UI.
The code I have is as follows:

```
to create-ICE-engine-cars
  let ICE-old (cars-ICE-engine * 0.65)
  let ICE-middle (cars-ICE-engine * 0.3)
  let ICE-new (cars-ICE-engine * 0.05)
  
  ask n-of ICE-old patches with [p-road-data > 9] 
  [sprout 1]

  ask n-of ICE-middle patches with [p-road-data > 9]
  [sprout 1]
  
  ask n-of ICE-new patches with [p-road-data > 9]
  [sprout 1]
end
```

I don't think it's really important if it rounds up or down for a given category. I just need to have the same amount of setup agents as the one defined in the UI. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Netlogo rounds floating point numbers down to the next integer when you try to use them for procedures like "sprout". So you will have to come up with some code to ensure that you still get some extra cars added in. One way to do it is to first create the numbers of cars you want and to change them later.

I am using lists so that the solution is easier to scale up or down. A possible solution is to see how many cars will already be created by rounding down the values that you have, then checking the difference between the cars you want and the total numbers of cars you will get. That number is how many extra cars you still need to assign. Finally we can take the fractional parts of the initial numbers by subtracting the original number by its rounded down form. We can see which of these fractional parts is the highest and then use its index to add one extra car to its associated integer part. We can do this multiple times by setting the highest fractional part to 0 after it has been chosen. That way it won't be chosen twice.

I've added a few extra car options just to show the scalability of this solution.

```
to go-3
  let cars-ICE-engine 111034

  ;Initiate multiple categories
  let ICE-old (cars-ICE-engine * 0.35)
  let ICE-middle (cars-ICE-engine * 0.3)
  let ICE-new (cars-ICE-engine * 0.05)
  let ICE-1 (cars-ICE-engine * 0.07)
  let ICE-2 (cars-ICE-engine * 0.10)
  let ICE-3 (cars-ICE-engine * 0.13)

  let ICE-list (list ICE-old ICE-middle ICE-new ICE-1 ICE-2 ICE-3) ;join all the categories into one lit
  let int-list map floor ICE-list ;Round all the numbers downfor the actual number of cars each category will get
  let fract-list (map [[a b] -> a - b] ICE-list int-list) ;Calculate the factional part of each number that you rounded down

  let cars-needed cars-ICE-engine - sum int-list
  
  repeat cars-needed [
  
    let max-fract max fract-list
    let max-index one-of filter [ i -> item i fract-list = max-fract] range length fract-list ;Find the index of the highest fractional value in the list. If there is a tie, pick one at random
    
    set int-list replace-item max-index int-list (item max-index int-list + 1) ;Increase the correct value of the int-list by 1
    set fract-list replace-item max-index fract-list 0 ;Set the correct value of the fractional list to 0 so that it isn't chosen multiple times
    
  ]
  
  print ICE-list
  print int-list
  print fract-list
  
end
```

A last approach does something similar but instead uses weighted means to determine which category gets the extra cars

```
to go-2
  let cars-ICE-engine 111034

  ;Initiate multiple categories
  let ICE-old (cars-ICE-engine * 0.35)
  let ICE-middle (cars-ICE-engine * 0.3)
  let ICE-new (cars-ICE-engine * 0.05)
  let ICE-1 (cars-ICE-engine * 0.07)
  let ICE-2 (cars-ICE-engine * 0.10)
  let ICE-3 (cars-ICE-engine * 0.13)
  
  let ICE-list (list ICE-old ICE-middle ICE-new ICE-1 ICE-2 ICE-3) ;join all the categories into one lit
  let int-list map floor ICE-list ;Round all the numbers downfor the actual number of cars each category will get
  let remainder-list (map [[a b] -> a - b] ICE-list int-list) ;Calculate the remainder for each number that you rounded down
   
  
  let to-distribute round sum remainder-list ;Calculate how many cars still need to be distributed
  
  repeat to-distribute [
    let number random-float to-distribute
    let flag False
    let cum-rem-list map [i -> sum sublist remainder-list 0 (i + 1)] range length remainder-list ;I create a new list where each value is the sum of itself and all prior values i nthe remainder-list This list is useful for selecting a category using a random weighted method
    
    foreach range length cum-rem-list [ i ->
      if not flag [
        if number <= item i cum-rem-list [
          set int-list replace-item i int-list (item i int-list + 1)  ;I increase the value of the selected category by 1
          set to-distribute to-distribute - item i remainder-list ;Subtract the selected value from t-distribute so that the newto-distribute is still the sum of everything in the remainder-list
          set remainder-list replace-item i remainder-list 0 ;I remove the selected value from the remainder-list so that it can't be selected again
          set flag True
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  
  print int-list
  print sum int-list
  
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a NetLogo question and there is no correct or optimal solution to it. It heavily depends on what is most important to you.

Probably the easiest solution is to assign 65% to ICE-old, 30% to ICE-middle, and the remaining cars to ICE-new. But be careful, this will lead to a bias! In the case of 10 cars, you will always end up with no ICE-new.

```
let cars-ICE-engine 10
let ICE-old (cars-ICE-engine * 0.65)
let ICE-middle (cars-ICE-engine * 0.3)
let ICE-new (cars-ICE-engine - ICE-old - ICE-middle)
```

Another solution would be to distribute the cars randomly, using your percentage values as probabilities. But a low number of cars or few repetitions of your simulations might not result in the correct percentages. As soon, as you draw enough random numbers, it will work without bias.

Option 1 with a nested

```
repeat total-cars [
let rnd_num random-float 1

ifelse rnd_num < new-prob 
[set ICE-new ICE-new + 1]
[ifelse rnd_num < middle-prob
  [set ICE-middle ICE-middle + 1]
  [set ICE-old ICE-old + 1]
]
```

]

Option 2 with `(ifelse)`

```
  repeat total-cars [
    let rnd_num random-float 1
    
    (ifelse 
      rnd_num < old-prob [set ICE-old ICE-old + 1]
      rnd_num < (old-prob + middle-prob) [set ICE-old ICE-old + 1]
      [set ICE-new ICE-new + 1]
     )
  ]
```

Comment: I edited my code right around when you posted it since I didn't like my original approach anymore. I switched to a less random system. So the first approach you are referring to in you last sentence no longer exists

Comment: Aight, thanks for letting me know! Deleted that last sentence.

Comment: HI all. Thank you for your interesting solutions. While I was waiting for answers, I kept playing around with a solution and in one of them I considered to use round in the let command: 
  let ICE-old round (cars-ICE-engine * 0.65)
  let ICE-middle round (cars-ICE-engine * 0.3)
  let ICE-new round (cars-ICE-engine * 0.05)
It gives me the cars I want, i.e., the same as in the UI. No risk in having no cars in any category because simulations will be run with hundreds of cars. I was just simplifying agent amounts to experiment. Is this super simple solution wrong?

Comment: Depends on what you refer to as "wrong". Your solution will result in most of the cases in your desired amount of total cars and is as close to your desired proportions as possible (fulfilling the total car condition). However, even for a large amount of cars there are cases where your solution will result in the wrong amount of total cars. 1012 would be such a case.

Comment: @Tanyta Even in your own example with 10 cars, using round will result in 7 old cars, 3 middle car and 1 new car. So 1 car too many.